# Why the UISegmentedControl works from back to front?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uisegmentedcontrol

I am developing an application for iOS (swift) and i can't understand why the UISegmentControl is behaving this way.
The segment 0 is the last and the segment 3 is the first.
this is my code(Is working fine now):

```
 @IBAction func SelectOptionInSegment(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0:
        sender.subviews[3].tintColor = segmentSelectedColor
        break
    case 1:
        sender.subviews[2].tintColor = segmentSelectedColor
        break
    case 2:
        sender.subviews[1].tintColor = segmentSelectedColor
        break
    case 3:
        sender.subviews[0].tintColor = segmentSelectedColor
        break
    default:

    }
```

Can someone explain this behaviour?

Comment: Can you please explain what is the issue you are facing and what was the desired output you were expecting ?

Comment: The code i'm using works, i only wanted to understand this strange behaviour of the segmented control. I am changing the color of the selected index in the segment, but when i used the correct order it was changing the wrong index. =(

Comment: You don't need to `break` at the end of your individual cases, and you need to do something in your `default` case (`break` if you don't plan on executing anything)

Comment: @douglazt: If a segment is selected and another one is chosen, you are not removing the tintColor of previously selected option.

Comment: @douglazt: did you try to set the tintColor of the UISegmentedControl?

Comment: @douglazt: are you trying to implement a multi selection segmented control? don't do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 things at play here.  The actual segments are numbered starting at 0 (you can verify this by putting a breakpoint on your switch statement.)  The .selectedSegment will coincide with what you are expecting.

Where it's getting confusing is the subviews.  The subview array is created in the order that the views are added, and that may not correlate with the segment order.  Most of the time you don't have to deal with the acutal view for each segment (there are other methods for this - most of the time).

So to answer your question - yes this is normal, but no - it's not very ideal.

Answer (score 2):

A Segmented control supports a variety of options for customizing it's appearance. (e.g. tint color, the methods for setting images for each segment, etc.)

If the docs don't list a public interface for manipulating the segmented control's subviews then those subviews are private and you should not try to manipulate them directly. Your code is fragile. Don't do that.

The order (and nature) of the subviews is a private implementation detail, and subject to change without notice. A future version of iOS might implement a segmented control as a totally custom object without any subviews, and the code you posted would break completely.